# How to deselect with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i would like to deselect and #id item from a selection without changing HTML or adding any classname,

lets say i want to emulate this Jquery sentence in CSS

```
 $('img').not('#thisone').CSS();
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS3's `:not()` selector (which has an equivalent [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector)):

```
img:not(#thisone) {
}
```

If you need better browser support, there's always the fact that ID selectors, being the most specific simple selectors, are good for overrides:

```
img {
    /* All images */
}

#thisone {
    /* Revert styles for this particular image */
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE < 9: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: Obligatory "I was just about to place an 'obligatory `:not()` has poor support comment here' comment but someone beat me to it" comment goes here.

Comment: #dmenu li img:not(#logo_web){ max-height:20px;}   netbeans jumps error like this, does it look ok for you??? thank you!!!

Comment: @Pekka: But every time I suggest `:not()`, someone just has to jump in, with a Quirksmode link or other, bitching about poor browser support. Gets old really quickly :P (no hard feelings though)

Comment: @Toni: I think NetBeans (whichever version you're using) doesn't support CSS3's new features. Just a guess though, as I don't use NetBeans for web dev.

Comment: @BoltClock well, you have to admit that missing IE support *is* sort of a setback. :) Even though it stinks that we have to think about such things in the first place... But that is a different story.

Comment: @Pekka: True, after all it took three versions from 6 to get support :/

Comment: yes gets me unexpected symbol, but well, it works; would need to check for IE now... thanks a lot

Comment: @Toni: I suggested an alternative that works with IE in case you need it.

Comment: true, that defenitely will solve it but i wanted to know if a deselector existed and it does, thanks a lot for you time!

Answer (score 0):

This might help
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

(Jquery does that internally anyway, I think, didn't check, though).

Comment: If the selector is compatible with the browser's `querySelectorAll` implementation, I guess yes jQuery does that internally, sort of