# Dom xml parsing and removing last node from the loop

Tags: xml

How do we remove or skip a node in a nest?

### Example

Below, how do I skip the last child of `<node id="1">`, which is `<node id="15">`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <node id="1" >
          <test1 key="">Bank</test1>
          <test2/>      
          <node id="2">
            <test1 >asdf2</test1>
              <test2>asdf2</test2>

            <node id="3">
              <test1 >asdf3</test1>
              <test2>asdf3</test2>

            </node>
            <node id="4">
             <test1 >asdf4</test1>
              <test2>asdf4</test2>

            </node>
            <node id="5">
              <test1 >asdf5</test1>
              <test2>asdf5</test2>
            </node>
            <node id="6">
             <test1 >asdf6</test1>
              <test2>asdf6</test2>
            </node>
            <node id="7">
              <test1 >asdf66</test1>
              <test2>asdf66</test2>
            </node>
            <node id="8">
              <test1 >asdf44</test1>
              <test2>asdf44</test2>
            </node>
          </node>
          <node id="9">
           <test1 >asd56f</test1>
              <test2>as56df</test2>
            <node id="10">
             <test1 >as56df</test1>
              <test2>asd56f</test2>
            </node>
            <node id="11">
              <test1 >as56df</test1>
              <test2>asd56f</test2>
            </node>
          </node>
          <node id="12">
            <test1 >asdf5</test1>
              <test2>asd6f</test2>
            <node id="13">
             <test1 >asd6f</test1>
              <test2>asd5f</test2>
            </node>
            <node id="14">
              <test1 >asdf55</test1>
              <test2>asdf55</test2>
            </node>
          </node>
          <node id="15">
            <test1 >asdf44</test1>
              <test2>asdf44</test2>
          </node>
        </node>
```

### I have tried:

```
if(childNodelist.item(i).getNodeName().equals("test1")){ some logic }
```

Comment: Dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793882/how-to-deselect-with-css; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101674/using-nth-child-to-target-every-other-two-divs

Comment: Very interesting question.  I tried this, and it failed to even select: `node[id="1"]:last-child`.  I had assumed: `node[id="1"]:last-child:not`....

Comment: Did you mean you are not able to get child nodes of first node ?

Comment: I did not see any helpful reply to this post, it's my first post and no response on it...

Comment: @user32669116 It's interesting, man.  It's possible that the programming language, itself, is incapable.  So, you'll have to use javascript to solve the problem.  I'll research this additionally and get back to you.  You've got a good point.  Try answering some questions and post a bounty next time, also. :)

Comment: to be fair, though: why do this with id's?  With classes, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`#1 > node:not(:last-child) {rule;}`

`#node` is the parent type.  `node:not` is the child element type.

So, if you had

```
<nodes id="container">
  <node></node>
  <node></node>
</nodes>
```

You would use: `nodes[id="container"] > node:not(:last-child) {rule;}`

Comment: Also, you can try without `:not`.  Use `nodes > node {rule} nodes > node:last-of-type {counter-rule;}`.  According to my sources, this is better for multiple reasons.